# VSTS Two identical builds not generating same amount of zip files

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, msbuild, azure-devops

I am currently facing an issue with our ASP.Net MVC solution with VSTS builds. We have two different builds that are configured exactly the same. Both generate a working website, but one is missing a zipped file.

The first build, let's call it ALPHA, is building the solution and generate two zipped files (A.zip and B.zip).

The second build, BRAVO, is building the solution and generate three zipped files (A.zip, B.zip, C.zip).

Here are the build parameter of both builds
Build 1

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\"
```

Build 2

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\"
```

I first looked at both build to compare **all** the parameters and they were identical. Following this, I decided to download the export of the build *(as xml)* to compete them and they both are identical *(Except for the links and one trigger)*. Now I am kind of stuck with that, the easy solution would be to create new builds until I can get two build working correctly, but I would prefer solving the issue instead.

If anyone have clues about this, it would be appreciated.

This question could relates to [TFS 2015 Visual Studio Build - Package .zip not being created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47745076/tfs-2015-visual-studio-build-package-zip-not-being-created)

Comment: Are they building the same solution, or are they building different solutions? If they're building different solutions, that would be the place to look.

Comment: They are building the same solution taken from the same git commit.

Comment: @Yannick Do you have two asp.net mvc projects in your solution file? What's the result if you build manually by msbuild cli? And what's the result if you build by Hosted VS2017 agent?

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT Thanks for your help. We currently have two MVC projects within the solution. The third one is a console app for a web job _(This is the one not generating a zip file in one of the two build)_. We are already using hosted VS2017 agent for both build. Building locally with msbuild generate the three zip file correctly.

Comment: @Yannick Can you share the detail build logs of the two build definition separately by setting `system.debug` as `true`?

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT Thanks for the feedback. Following your request on build, I've revised them entirely and found the solution to my problem. It seems that using the nuget restore step wasn't working at all. I had to check the `Restore NuGet Packages` within the build step. It seems to be deprecated, but works on my build..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolve my issue by adding the `Restore NuGet Packages` check box within my *Build Solution* step. It seems that the *NuGet Restore* step didn't work well with my solution, I don't quite get why.

Note that this option is deprecated and shouldn't be used, but at the end of the day, it solved my issue!